# Laravel 5.7 Create Enable and Disable Disable Active Link in route.php file from Amin Page Views

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel 5.7 project for international conference. I want to make an admin page that can enable and disable submission form link if it's already pass the deadline.

Is that any possible way to access the route.php files to enable or disable any link in route.php files or any java scripts or any possible way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help you, we need to see your code -- if it's not top-secret-hush-hush, paste it into your question ([not an image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)), select it, and use the editor's code button.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't change route.php content, but you can check submission status (disable/enable)/(already passed the deadline) and return continue or die script in the controller page or if you're going to use it a lot, you can make special middleware for it and add it to the kernel file